# passing Form value to a xmlhttpPost function

Tags: javascript, ajax

HI

How do i pass a value from a form to an Ajax function which will use that value to build a URL

```
<FORM id="form" METHOD="GET" ACTION="">
<b> Enter argument: </b>
<input size="40" name="q" value="">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset">
</FORM>


function xmlhttpPost(){
$tag = q.value
$search = 'http://...&tag=$tag'
$search = encodeURIComponent($search)
request = new ajaxRequest()
request.open("GET","xmlget.php?url=" + $search, true)
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. You should declare variables with `var`

   ```
   var $tag = ... ;
   ```
2. You should give your `<input>` an "id", and use "document.getElementById()" to locate the element:

   ```
   var $tag = document.getElementById('q');
   ```
3. The value should be appended to the string, and only that should be passed to "encodeURIComponent":

   ```
   var $search = 'http://...&tag=' + encodeURIComponent($tag);
   ```

**edit** — A wise commenter points out that the apparent use o the URL in your sample code is such that you probably **would** want to encode the whole thing.  That is, if what you want to do is pass a URL string entirely as a parameter value via *another* URL, then yes you would pass the whole thing to "encodeURIComponent".  The point is that you have to make sure you encode the bits that should *not* be interpreted by the browser and server as part of URL syntax.  Therefore, point 3 above may not apply (well it does, but it applies to the final URL, not the URL that's going to end up as a parameter).

Comment: can you point me to how i can trigger the Ajax call?

Comment: You should encode the whole search string as the OP passes the whole URL to a PHP script .. a proxy most likely ..

Comment: Well, that *might* be appropriate, but I doubt it - once the components of the URL have been encoded, it would only be necessary to encode other parts of the string if the API it were being sent to is completely broken.

Comment: the `&tag` part of the `$search` variable would break the url since the `&` would be considered to define a new url parameter. Notice that the whole `$search` is being concatenated to the destination url with `"xmlget.php?url=" + $search`

Comment: @Gaby -- **oh** now I see what you mean. Durrr.  Sorry about that :-)  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can partially answer your question.  To get the value from the input control use:

```
document.getElementById("id").value
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: [Please don't use w3schools.com for, well, anything.](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, if I've read this right, you're just asking "how do I get the value out of a textbox in JavaScript?". If so, then this should do the trick:

```
<FORM id="form" METHOD="GET" ACTION="">
<b> Enter argument: </b>
<input size="40" name="q" id="q" value="">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset">
</FORM>

function xmlhttpPost(){
var tag = document.getElementById('q').value;
var search = 'http://...&tag=' + tag;
search = encodeURIComponent(search)
request = new ajaxRequest()
request.open("GET","xmlget.php?url=" + search, true)
```

Note, the id attribute on the input.

Comment: No, that's not quite going to do the trick ...

Comment: Whoops. Didn't actually check to make sure the original JavaScript was correct. My bad. I've edited to fix.

Comment: It's also going to be a problem that the whole URL is being passed to "encodeURIComponent", because that will encode everything, including the slashes and the "&".  It really only has to be used on the *value* of the `<input>` in this case (of course we can't see the actual URL in the sample code ...)

Comment: could i use the action to both pass the value AND trigger the xmlhttpPost function?